# Python interpreter, virtual environments and pycharm

Tags: python, interpreter, pycharm, arcpy

Platform Windows. IDE PyCharm CE.

I have a script that uses module ArcPy from ESRI. This module has its own Python 2.6. I have to import a module that uses dictionary comprehensions not supported by Python 2.6.

How do I work around this without rewriting the code to avoiding list comprehensions?

Other questions:

- What should be the correct pattern for project creation and interpreter maintenance? Should I always use virtual dedicated envs for each project importing any needed modules and keep isolation for each?
- Is it correct to import the extra needed packages for my projects to the ArcPy python installation Python 2.6.5 (C:/Python26/ArcGIS10.0/python.exe)? Can this cause problems later to arc map?

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade your ArcGis Python 2.6 release to 2.7. 
If you need Python 3, it won't work, because arcpy works only in Python 2.

Comment: Nope its seems not possible to use 2.7 as far as can understand from some ESRI staff post below.http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/2506-arcpy-install-fears?p=8475&viewfull=1#post8475

Comment: @JorgeVidinha It IS definitely possible to run python 2.7 with arcpy. I have it running myself with python 2.7.5. The post you linked is 4 years old, stuff have happened since then. Last time i checked arcgis ships with python 2.7.x